# Optimal Colouring given Chromatic No.

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a way to colour a graph 'optimally' given its chromatic number....other than taking maximum independent sets, brute force I can't think of any extravagant way...

Comment: Maybe assign each number a color, draw a line from each vertex to the center, then color each section in a clockwise order using the number from the corresponding vertex

Comment: @JosephEck how is the center defined?

Comment: Optimal in what sense? What makes one proper colouring with $\chi(G)$ colours better than another?